# Receiving POST submission in Play Framework/Scala REST service

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have looked online and cannot make this work. I just need to receive POST fields submitted from a browser to the server. The form is submitted with a single JSON object.

This is what I've got:

```
  case class Us (firstName: String, lastName: String)

  def applyUser = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) {

    val userForm = Form(
      mapping(
        "first" -> text,
        "last" -> text
      )(Us.apply)(Us.unapply)
    )

    val json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq("ret" -> JsString("0")))
    Ok(json)

}
```

I get the following error: `Expression of type Result doesn't conform to expected type (Request[JsValue]) => Result`

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Action apply method expects a function rather than a Result object. Try the following:

```
case class Us (firstName: String, lastName: String)

  def applyUser = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { body => //This is the change required to your code

    val userForm = Form(
      mapping(
        "first" -> text,
        "last" -> text
      )(Us.apply)(Us.unapply)
    )

    val json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq("ret" -> JsString("0")))
    Ok(json)

}
```